# How to let nifi in docker can access my custom processor nar file?

Tags: docker-compose, apache-nifi

Environment:

- OS: Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS
- Docker: 23.0
- NIFI: 1.20.0

I use docker-compose.yml to build a nifi in docker.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2.16.0"
services:
  nifi-1:
    image: apache/nifi:1.20.0
    container_name: nifi-1
    hostname: nifi-1
    ports:
      - 9080:9080
    environment:
      - NIFI_REMOTE_INPUT_SECURE=false
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT=
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT=
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=9080
      - NIFI_SECURITY_KEYSTORE=
      - NIFI_SECURITY_KEYSTORE_TYPE=
      - NIFI_SECURITY_TRUSTSTORE=
      - NIFI_SECURITY_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE=
    volumes:
      - /opt/nifi-3rd-lib:/opt/nifi-3rd-lib
```

I have developed my custom processors and packed them into a nar file (say foo.nar) and put it in `/opt/nifi-3rd-lib` in host. I want my nifi in docker can use foo.nar. What should I do ?

My original thought is:

1. put foo.jar in `/opt/nifi-3rd-lib` in host
2. Add (or change) classpath for nifi in docker-compose.yml (**but I don't know how to make it**)

Therefore, the second thought is:

1. Start docker-compose (but don't start nifi yet)
2. Ask docker-compose to copy foo.nar in host into `nifi-current/lib` in container (**I don't know how to do it neither**)
3. start nifi

So, could anyone give instructions for either the above thoughts ? appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#autoloading-processors

the `nifi.nar.library.autoload.directory` property must be configured to point at the desired directory. By default, this points at `./extensions`.

So, just map local folder with all your custom nar files into `${NIFI_HOME}/extensions` folder

Normally `NIFI_HOME=/opt/nifi/nifi-current` but please doublecheck nifi location in your container

```
    volumes:
      - /opt/local-nar/:/opt/nifi/nifi-current
```

---

official Dockerfile located here: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-docker/dockerhub/Dockerfile - it could give you better understanding how you could change the behavior of dockerized nifi.

---

As alternative option you could change an `entrypoint` of image using `docker-compose.yml` and run own script just before starting nifi. like this:

```yaml
version: "2.16.0"
services:
  nifi-1:
    ...
    volumes:
      - /opt/nifi-3rd-lib:/opt/nifi-3rd-lib
    entrypoint: /opt/nifi-3rd-lib/pre_start.sh && ../scripts/start.sh
```

and in `pre_start.sh` you can copy all required files into `${NIFI_HOME}/extensions`. NIFI_HOME variable should be available in script..